# Como criar uma propriedade em Visual Studio C# que abre a caixa de edição

Tags: c#, propriedade

Gostaria que alguém me ajudasse com uma situação.
Quem tiver um exemplo me responda por favor.
Gostaria de criar uma propriedade em um objeto Controle de Usuário, e que, nessa
propriedade abrisse a caixa de edição, como exemplo a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código do meu Controle de Usuário:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp13
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Propriedade para informar um texto fixo.
        public string MyObservacao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Desculpe, não consegui entender o que você querendo fazer.

Comment: Em Visual Studio c# eu criei um Controle de Usuário (ObservacaoGeral) uma caixa de texto multi-line. Neste Controle de Usuario eu criei uma propriedade MyTextInitial onde, quando eu coloco meu controle no formulário eu vou nessa propriedade e coloco o texto que eu quero. Só que nessa propriedade aparece apenas uma linha pra eu digitar e eu gostaria que minha propriedade abrisse a caixa de texto como no exemplo postado acima. A propriedade nativa do Text abre a caixa de edição. Eu queria que isso acontecesse com a minha propriedade MyTextInitial. Att. Gilberto Rezende.

Comment: Evoluindo... quando você diz `Visual Studio C#` e `Controle de Usuário` você está se referindo de fato a um componente e você quer que a edição de um atributo, na aba propriedades da IDE, apresente como multiline? Inclua o código do componente em sua pergunta.

Comment: Grato.
Segue código do meu Controle de Usuário:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp13
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // Propriedade para informar um texto fixo.
        public string MyObservacao { get; set; }
    }
}

Att.

Gilberto Rezende.

Comment: utilize a opção de editar e coloque essa informação na pergunta

Comment: Adicione a referência para a `System.Design` em seu projeto e a seguinte anotação na propriedade em que deseja que o editor seja multiline         
`[Editor(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]`

Comment: Muito bom. Deu tudo certo. Sou imensamente grato.
Att. 
Gilberto Rezende.